# How to Change the orientation of a ExtJS Gridpanel look  like a property grid?

Tags: extjs, grid, orientation, propertygrid, datastore

I would like to have a grid which look like a property grid. Like a normal grid flipped the orientation.
Like a  Property grid with multiple columns. Is is possible to load data into a propertycolumnmodel from a Datastore?  It would be great if anyone can help me with a working example in EXtjS 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the [Sencha/ExtJS 3.4](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/) examples, you'll find this [*property grid*](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/property-grid.html) example.

Thanks for helping me discorver it - even though I've been to the examples several times a day :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I spend lot of time with that  example before I post the question. My issue is  I am not able to load the data from my Ext.Datastore.  I tried to load the store via the store config option of the property-grid.  Actually I want  something a normal grid look like a pivot grid like view.  I tried to use the pivot-grid also ,but was not successful. I want a result something like a form panel type view. Field names in the first column and the values in the next columns. I couldn't find a proper example for this. It would be great if you can give me some more clue.

Comment: Looking at the API (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/), I think you can use an `Ext.grid.PropertyStore` and an `Ext.grid.PropertyColumnModel` to do exactly what you would do in a normal grid.